# DataTarget to 'editPage' pass to edit page 'edit.cshtml'

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I recently started learning Razor pages so please bear with me....I have an index.cshtml razor page that displays a database data into a table. each row has an edit button that targets a model page 'editpage' . how will i pass or call the target-page 'editpage' from my index.cshtml to my edit.cshtml page that has a modal view.

```html
<---Index.cshtml--->>
@foreach ( var item in Model.Ceding ) {
<tr>
  <td>@item.FirstName</td>
  <td>@item.MiddleInitial</td>
  <td>@item.LastName</td>
  <td>@item.Gender</td>
  <td>@item.DateofBirth</td>
  <td>@item.CedingCompany</td>
  <td>@item.PlanEffectiveDate</td>
  <td>@item.SumAssured</td>
  <td>@item.ReinsuredNetAmount</td>
  <td>@item.Status</td>
  <td>
    <div class="form-button-action">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-simple-primary btn-lg" data-target="#editPage"><a class="fa fa-edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"></a>
      </button>
      <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-link btn-simple-danger" data- original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
       </button>
    </div>

  </td>
</tr>
} 


<---Edit.cshtml--->>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="editPage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-      labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="display-5" id="exampleModalLabel">EDIT DETAILS</h2>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
         </button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 
 Controller:
  public IEnumerable<Cedants> Ceding { get; set; }

  public IndexModel( AppDbContext db )
  {
      _db = db;
  }

  public void OnGet(int id)
  {

   Ceding = _db.dbo_life.ToList(); //retrieves data in database

  }
```

Comment: Would you kind include your `code snippet` instead of screenshots. So that it could be reproduce and resolved quickly.

Comment: For testing purposes, try to add `asp-action` in the a tag `<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a>`. See whether it works.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron , please see the code above. thank you so much to the support

Comment: How's your `Model.Ceding` detaitls? Additionally include your `Controller` as well so that your problem full explained and can be resolved faster.

Comment: See this article on using Bootstrap modals with Razor Pages: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/349/razor-pages-and-bootstrap-modal-master-details

Comment: I was able to resolved this by creating a partial view and  calling the modal class body from ajax on my Index View.